# Transition only inside the overlayarea

Tags: beamer

I want the `\transpush` or `\transcover` to work only inside the **overlayarea**. It works with for example `\transglitter`:

```
 \begin{block}{Transition in block}
\begin{overlayarea}{\textwidth}{3cm}
\only<1>{
This is the first text, which is to be covered}
\only<2>{This is a new text that covers the previous
\transglitter<2>[duration=1]}
\end{overlayarea}
\end{block}
```

But when I use

```
\begin{block}{Transition in block}
\begin{overlayarea}{\textwidth}{3cm}
\only<1>{
This is the first text, which is to be covered}
\only<2>{This is a new text that covers the previous
\transcover<2>[direction=90,duration=1]}
\end{overlayarea}
\end{block}
```

it does not work. Has anybody some solution?

MWE may look like this:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usetheme{Berlin}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Transition 1}
\begin{block}{Transition in block}
\begin{overlayarea}{\textwidth}{3cm}
\only<1>{
This is the first text, which is to be covered}
\only<2>{This is a new text that covers the previous
\transglitter<2>[duration=1]}
%works inside overlayarea
\end{overlayarea}
\end{block}
\end{frame}


\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Transition 2}
\begin{block}{Transition in block}
\begin{overlayarea}{\textwidth}{3cm}
\only<1>{
This is the first text, which is to be covered}
\only<2>{This is a new text that covers the previous
\transcover<2>[direction=90,duration=1]}
%works with whole slide
\end{overlayarea}
\end{block}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome ! Could you provide us a MWE : http://minimalbeispiel.de/mini-en.html

Answer (score 1):

The overlay always works for the whole slide. In the first example you just don't notice it, as the text outside the block is the same, but try with:

```
\begin{frame} 
\frametitle{Transition 1} 
\only<1>{some text outside} 
\only<2>{other text} 
\begin{block}{Transition in block} 
\begin{overlayarea}{\textwidth}{3cm} 
\only<1>{ This is the first text, which is to be covered} 
\only<2>{This is a new text that covers the previous \transglitter<2>[duration=1]} %works inside overlayarea 
\end{overlayarea} 
\end{block} 
\end{frame}
```

As far as I understand the overlay animations are also something from the pdf format (in interaction with the viewer) itself, so latex does not have influence, which parts of the page are animated in the transition, its always the whole page.

Comment: It can be solved by this code:

Comment: \begin{frame}      \frametitle{Transition 1}        \only<1>{some text outside}       \only<2->{other text}       \begin{block}{Transition in block}    \begin{overlayarea}{\textwidth}{3cm}   \only<1-3>{ This is the first text, which is to be covered}  \only<4>{This is a new text that covers the previous  \transglitter<4>[duration=1]}  %works inside overlayarea   \end{overlayarea}  \end{block}   \end{frame}

Comment: @hearth No, this is the same phenomena as your first example. You use the transglitter transition when nothing outside of the block changes, so you don't see that the whole slide does this transition and not just the block, as you claim.

Comment: But I want to use the \transpush in the exactly same situation,when nothing outside the block is changing.

Comment: I know that you want to do this :) But due to the kind of animation you want to use, you will always see that in reality the whole page is changing. `\transglitter` is just a serendipitous example where you don't notice the effect.

Comment: I wrote \transcover originally, but \transpush causes the same troubles.